# How to associate a single image with a content type in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

This may be a dumb question, but partly for posterity's sake, I want to ask it. I am sure that others who are learning how to use Orchard for the first time will wonder it as well.

I want to create a content type (preferably from within the CMS itself) that has a single image as one of its content parts. The goal is to present users creating a new instance of the content type with a field that includes a single image upload which will be the featured image for that content type. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two fields you can add to your content type that will do this:

Image Field
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.ImageField

Or

Media Picker Field (included in Orchard 1.6)

Comment: Thanks! I tried the latter option and discovered (for anyone that reading this page that doesn't already know) that the media picker can be set to only allow a single image to be chosen.